# Desktop motherboard clicking, power cycling - no POST beeps. CPU and memory make no difference

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, desktop-computer

I recently bought a Gigabyte motheroard and a CPU off eBay, but I tried turning them on with two different PSUs and every time I clicked the power on button the following happens:

- two quiet clicks from the motherboard speaker
- the CPU and PSU fan turn on (I haven't tried chasis fans)
- theres a third quiet click from the speaker
- the fans stop spinning
- the process restarts over and over
  This happens regardless of if the CPU/memory are in. There's never any video output or POST beeps.

If I unplug the CPU power cable, the speaker gives two, much quieter, clicks and keeps trying to turn on as before.I've tried resetting the BIOS by taking out the CMOS battery but it makes no difference.

Does anyone know what kind of component error this must involve and what I may need to replace? I have experience fixing up GPUs with blown components but I'm not sure how to diagnose voltages or resistances on a motherboard. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

- I've tried checking the MOSFETS near the CPU against ground with a resistometer on continuity mode but I don't think they're shorting
- I powered it on and checked the voltage on the inductors near the CPU and theyre around 1.8 volts. The memory inductors get 5 volts.

Comment: Sounds like either the CPU or motherboard is not operational.  In order to determine which one is not operational you would need a known good CPU to verify if the motherboard is operational.  Do you have access to one?

Answer (score 0):

The motherboard was at fault. Returning it. I got a working cpu and motherboard to see what was broken and it was the motherboard.